# Read only view how do I disable?

Tags: microsoft-office

I am using MS 2010 and want to send attachments that do not open as Read Only. I already disabled protected view in the trust center but it is still not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: That is dependent on the recipients settings not the senders ...

Comment: Is there some setting I can put on the Word document itself?

Comment: No. See the answer by music2myear.

Answer (score 1):

When Word opens a Document file that has come via email or any other source over the internet, it always opens by default in Read-Only.

So long as there is not security applied to the document protecting it from further edits, the reader should be able to click the appropriate "Edit" button to "unlock" the file for editing.